# Xpath is found even though web object not visible

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, null, visible

I am automating a code using selenium 2.0. I select one (or several) user(s) from a list. Then I click on an add button which makes the user name(s) visible on a grid. Each user will have a valid Xpath when visible on the grid. However, even after erasing all  user names from the grid which actually disappears if there is no user names displayed, the Xpath still does not return null. I am using Xpath to check if it returns null when the object (user name) is not visible, but it does not work as expected. Is there any other way to solve my problem? I am pretty new with Selenium. I am using selenium 2.0. Bellow is a section of my code. Your help will be very appreciated.

```
//Check if user is present on the grid
By checkuser = By.xpath( ".//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr/td[1]/span");

 //if the grid is not empty, which means the grid is visible...
if(null!=checkuser)   //where the problem is!!
{
    //Click the button to erase the names in the grid, then the grid desapears
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span")).click();
       Thread.sleep(2000);

    //more code
    //............

}
```

Comment: Element exists != visible. What do you expect? It's hard to tell, please show HTML or screenshot of UI if possible.\

Comment: Please post the html. The code null!=checkuser does not make too much sense. But if you want to really find out if an element is present or not you can use element.isDisplayed()

Comment: Just an aside your `if` logic seems logically incorrect. You are saying if "null is not the same as the value of checkuser" ...this should be if "the value of checkuser is not null" ...and anyway, why would your `checkuser` value ever be null? Seems a pointless excerise.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two things happening here:

First is that your XPath is generic enough that it is selecting some other element that isn't a user.  To see if this is the case, then in Chrome, go to the page and do the necessary actions to get it in the state you want.  Next, press Ctrl-Shift-J, click on Console, and type in `$x("//*[@id='sharing_list']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span")`.  Chrome will then show you which element your selector is selecting.

Your task then, is to identify if its selecting some other element, or whether the element is just not visible.  It is definitely possible to have an element on a page, but not visible, and WebDriver WILL select invisible elements (unless you are doing `By.linkText()`).  If you want to check to see if an element is visible do a `element.isDisplayed()`.

Comment: +1. That last part of T4000's xpath ("tbody/tr/td[1]/span") looks dangerous; in a dynamically-updated webpage, there's no guarantee that that xpath matches any given user's details. It's worth looking into alternative xpaths using IDs or inner text perhaps; they might give you a better fix on the user info.